# Which PC game had an island surrounded by swamps, skeletons, pinkish giants and huge spiders?

Tags: story-identification, video-games

**Game Mechanics:** This is a third-person perspective game (similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ARbSg3f5rc)) that I played about 10 years ago. The main character is initially placed in a small island surrounded by swamps. The tasks are usually obtained by speaking to the people in the island. The island is surrounded by skeletons close by, then big pinkish giants that follow to kill you, then poisonous plants like Venus flytraps which spit and also huge spiders (5x or greater than your size) as you get deeper into the swamps. The island that you start with is free from any danger. The missions take you deeper and deeper into the swamps, gradually.

Gold or weapons fall from them when you kill one; weapons have different categories like slow, fast, very fast, single-handed, double-handed, etc., with close combat and range weapons. You also have spells with high range. You get transported to a different place when you reach one side of the map, where you get to fight the boss.

**Plot:** One mission I remember is a islander asking your character to help recover his gas station in the swamps, which is now covered by those poisonous plants. Various tasks take you to different places in the swamps.

Some characters even accompanies you through the rest of the game, fighting with you, as a result of some successful mission.
Another task rewards you with a character which will accompany you to heal you when you complete their missions.

In the whole game, I haven't seen a house, just tents that too just on the initial island and no guns either.

Comment: For those voting to close, you might want to note that [**Video Games are on-topic**](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/are-video-games-out-of-scope)

Comment: No by 3D I just three directional movement and not like claws and no it didn't look like him and I played in 2007 approx so it is old. Plotline yes I will add to the question.

Comment: [More like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ARbSg3f5rc) the camera angle was a little higher from the character than that one, that's all.

Comment: So... wait... it's third-person camera, like in that video, with the player on-screen, right?  Not first-person?  And you're a character with weapons and magic spells... freeing a gas station?  (and 10 years is old?  *cries*)

Comment: Yes 3rd person camera @Radhil

Comment: Did you play this on PC?

Comment: Yes, I did play this on PC